# Is "the" part of a name?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Some expressions that uniquely identify an entity are always used with "the", for example "the untyped lambda calculus" or "the South Pole". Is the article a part of the name? In particular, when I want to write a link to such an expression, should the link include "the" or not? As in

> The [**Geographic South Pole**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Pole) should not be confused with the [**South Magnetic Pole**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Magnetic_Pole).

vs

> [**The Geographic South Pole**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Pole) should not be confused with [**the South Magnetic Pole**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Magnetic_Pole).

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your examples, it is better not to include the **the** in the link, usually it is best to keep the **link text** as small as possible.

For some reason, I feel the **the** in your examples should not be capitalised, it would't look right. However, in:

> **The** Great State of Georgia

the **the** should be capitalised.

If **the** is actually part of the name is, as in a title, **The Duke of Edinburgh**, the **the** should be capitalised. Another example is:

> Every year, **the boat race** held in Martha's Vineyard...
>   Every year, **The Boat Race** is held on the Thames...

The first refers to an annual boat race in the US, the second refers to the annual rowing competition between Oxford and Cambridge in London.